# Transparent image on website shows placeholder instead of transparency

Tags: html, css

I have a website were I used [html4up.com](https://html5up.net/dimension) template. I changed the diamond at the top to display an image with a transparent background. When I display the website, it's showing a square background were the transparency of the image is located.

How do I remove this background? I don't understand why it's displaying.

Here is an example:

[image]

I checked the image in Gimp and a few other applications and they show the image is transparent.

This is the header HTML where I'm displaying the image:

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <span class="image main"><img src="images/me.png" alt="" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>Fred</h1>
            <p>Someone Special</p>
            <p>Website still in process of being updated!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxx/" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```css
/* Header */

#header {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.325s ease-in-out, -moz-filter 0.325s ease-in-out, opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.325s ease-in-out, -webkit-filter 0.325s ease-in-out, opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.325s ease-in-out, -ms-filter 0.325s ease-in-out, opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.325s ease-in-out, filter 0.325s ease-in-out, opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55%);
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
    
#header > * {
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.325s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
}

#header > *:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(-3.5rem - 1px);
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    width: 1px;
    height: calc(3.5rem + 1px);
    background: #ffffff;
}

#header > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#header > :first-child:before {
    display: none;
}

#header .logo {
    width: 5.5rem;
    height: 5.5rem;
    line-height: 5.5rem;
    border: solid 1px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#header .logo .icon:before {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#header .content {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Is it the image I need to change? I have it as a PNG file.

**EDIT**

Maybe I do not understand the answer given below but I added the below:

```
    <div class="logo">
        <span class="image main"><img border-radius="50%" src="images/eric.png" alt="" /></span>
    </div>
```

It didn't make any difference:

[image: website]

Comment: The current answer below should work, or add overflow:hidden to the image container where has border-radius set, you probably has responsive image set up somewhere, anyway here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/83utnj2h/ some changes see comments there

Comment: @Stickers sorry, I hadn't seen this comment. I'm looking at jsfiddle now.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's response. I found out it was the background color that was interfering with the image.  `background-color: rgba(19, 21, 25, 0.5);`. Once I commented this out, it worked fine.

Comment: That is not anywhere in the code you shared. Which is why we ask for a [mre] ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply `border-radius: 50%;` to the `img` element.